# Write 20 Bytes command on BLE device using IONIC CAPACITOR application

Tags: arrays, typescript, ionic-framework, bluetooth-lowenergy

Hi there guy's i'm developing an application that connects to a BLE device. Now i need need to write theese 20 Bytes on the device using BleClient.write

```
34h 01h 50h 4Fh 4Ch 49h 54h 45h 43h 00 00 00h 00h 00h 00h 00h 00h 00h 00h 00h
```

but the write function ask me DATAVIEW... how i can send theese bytes to the device?

```
BleClient.write(device.deviceId, '02366e80-cf3a-11e1-9ab4-0002a5d5c51b', '340a1b80-cf4b-11e1-ac36-0002a5d5c51b', '34h 01h 50h 4Fh 4Ch 49h 54h 45h 43h 00 00 00h 00h 00h 00h 00h 00h 00h 00h 00h');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://github.com/capacitor-community/bluetooth-le#write) of the `write` method you can create a dataview using the `numbersToDataView` helper method. It accepts an array of numbers.

The [usage section](https://github.com/capacitor-community/bluetooth-le#usage) even includes an example which uses the helper:

```
await BleClient.write(device.deviceId, POLAR_PMD_SERVICE, POLAR_PMD_CONTROL_POINT, numbersToDataView([1, 0]));
console.log('written [1, 0] to control point');
```

In your case it is probably

```
numbersToDataView([34h, 01h, 50h, 4Fh, 4Ch, 49h, 54h, 45h, 43h, 00, 00, 00h, 00h, 00h, 00h, 00h, 00h, 00h, 00h, 00h])
```

Comment: works as expected! But only on certain browsers

Comment: I think not every browser supports all features of web BLE. Chrome should be the most supported